# gradle.build Android Kotlin with spotless and ktlint

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I came across this gradle build in android-sunflow app from codelabs while I am learning about android architecture components. spotless and ktlint in gradle built and task clean is commented. 
In build.gradle(project: MyApplication)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
    kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    ktlint_version = "0.32.0"
}

plugins {
    id "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless" version "3.23.0"
}
//task clean(type: Delete) {
//    delete rootProject.buildDir
//}

spotless {
    kotlin {
        target "**/*.kt"
        ktlint(ktlint_version)
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is it for and what is the benefit of using this?

Comment: using spotless you will face many issues, just try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74249501/6236959
It will add ktlint format with baseline and will fix files with pre-commit

Answer (score 2):

It helping to keep code clean by formatting them into specific rules. In that case they use to formatting kotlin kode based on ktlint (https://ktlint.github.io/). So by running a task `./gradlew spotlessApply` it will automatically fix the kotlin file format, for example consistent spacing like this:

```
// multiple spaces after "val long" for vertical alignment
val short = ""
val long  = ""
```

into

```
val short = ""
val long = ""
```

They can run it manually from terminal or integrate this with CI for automation.