# How to configure ktlint gradle plugin in a continuous mode?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, ktlint

In my Android Studio app project, I've integrated [ktlint gradle](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle#simple-setup).

**Is it possible to configure the ktlint gradle plugin, so that it runs continuously on the fly (while coding on the keyboard)??** Like [ESlint](https://eslint.org/) is used for JS, it warns me immediately if any lint warnings occur..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do that. *klint* is not a [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tool.

Alternatively, you can write custom [lint rules](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint) for the same. Here are some resources for doing so:

1. [Android Dev summit 2018 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffH-LD5uP4s)
2. [Android Dev summit 2019 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCmJWOkjbM0&vl=en)
3. [Android source code for standard lint rules](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/studio-master-dev/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks)
4. Repos

   1. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules
   2. https://github.com/tikurahul/lint-experiments
   3. https://github.com/vanniktech/lint-rules

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in Intellij / Android Studio if you install the [ktlint IDEA plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15057-ktlint-unofficial-).

It's also configurable so you can represent findings as warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of googling and exploring about ktlint we can setup like this

module(ex: app) level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint'

dependencies {}

ktlint {
    version = "0.48.2"
    debug = true
    verbose = true
    android = true
    outputToConsole = true
    outputColorName = "RED"
    ignoreFailures = true
    enableExperimentalRules = true
    additionalEditorconfig = [ // not supported until ktlint 0.49
                               "max_line_length": "20"
    ]
    disabledRules = ["final-newline"] // not supported with ktlint 0.48+
    baseline = file("${projectDir}/config/ktlint/baseline.xml")
    reporters {
        reporter "plain"
        reporter "checkstyle"
        reporter "sarif"
    }
    kotlinScriptAdditionalPaths {
        include fileTree("scripts/")
    }
    filter {
        exclude("**/generated/**")
        include("**/kotlin/**")
    }
}
```

project level build

```
plugins {
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "12.1.0" apply false
}

allprojects {
    task copyGitHooks(type: Copy) {
        description = "Copies the git hooks from /git-hooks to the .git folder."
        group = "git hooks"
        from "$rootDir/scripts/pre-commit"
        into "$rootDir/.git/hooks/"
    }

    task installGitHooks(type: Exec) {
        description = "Installs the pre-commit git hooks from /git-hooks."
        group = "git hooks"
        workingDir rootDir
        commandLine "chmod", "-R", "+x", ".git/hooks/"
        dependsOn copyGitHooks
        doLast {
            logger.info("Git hook installed successfully.")
        }
    }
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.tasks.findByName("preBuild") != null) {
            project.tasks.named("preBuild") { dependsOn "installGitHooks" }
        }
    }
}
```

Create a pre-commit(no extension) file inside a scripts folder [project top level]

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "............Starting ktlint check......................................"

echo "Started Formitting...."

./gradlew ktlintFormat

#
#echo ".....Staging all file changed during ktlint formatting................."
#
#git add .

echo "Completed.............................................................."
```

To enable git hook you need to run git config core.hooksPath .git/hooks

You need to create ktlint baseline for each module

Steps:

- Sync
- Gradle Tasks
- App Module Tasks
- help
- ktlintGenerateBaseline

or from terminal you can run `./gradlew :app:ktlintGenerateBaseline`

Using extension you can setup this by installing

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/files/15057/287040/ktlint-0.12.0.zip?updateId=287040&pluginId=15057&family=INTELLIJ

[image]

Comment: https://gptshubham595.medium.com/how-do-you-add-ktlint-to-a-multimodular-android-project-4a77083750e3